# Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Sorted and not Sorted. Retreival time

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

From MSDN:

> The `SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic class is a binary
>   search tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements
>   in the dictionary

From MSDN:

> Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1),
>   because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class is implemented as a
>   hash table.

My question is twofold:

1. what is `O(log n)` and `O(1)`; and
2. what makes `Dictionary` (not sorted) very fast? Does it need much more memory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: When `O(1)` -time performance is a constant; `O(log n)` - time performance described by the logarithmic dependence.

Answer (score 2):

`O(n)` is notation used to denote a weak upper bound. `O(log n)` means that an operation takes about log n steps to complete (it depends on the size of the input). `O(1)` means that the time to access is bounded by a constant, instead of the size of the input.

The Dictionary class has amortized constant access (but is not necessarily guaranteed because it might have to resize), where as the the SortedDictionary will have guaranteed access time of O(log n) because it is built from a tree.

Here's a nice intro to hash tables: [hash tables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/hash_data_structure.htm)